# How to exclude certain directories while using wget?

Tags: wget, exclude

I'd like to download a directory from a FTP, which contains some source codes.
Initially, I did this:

```
wget -r ftp://path/to/src
```

Unfortunately, the directory itself is a result of a SVN checkout, so there are lots of .svn directories, and crawling over them would take longer time. Is it possible to exclude those .svn directories?

Answer (score 24):

```
wget -X directory_to_exclude[,other_directory_to_exclude] -r ftp://URL_ftp_server
```

---

```
SERVER
    |-logs
    |-etc
    |-cache
    |-public_html
      |-images
      |-videos ( want to exclude )
      |-files
      |-audio  (want to exclude)
```

---

```
wget -X /public_html/videos,/public_html/audio ftp:SERVER/public_html/*
```

Comment: This actually seems to be the correct comment. The exclude-directories switch does not do patterns/regexes, so you have to include the entire path (from root). The higher-voted answer seems to be incorrect for all but the trivial cases.

Comment: I agree.  Although the documentation states that wildcards can be used, I could not get them to work.

Comment: wildcards work, but are interpreted first on shell level, so you have to escape them to work.

Answer (score 6):

```
wget --exclude-directories=.svn -r ftp://path/to/src
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to answer this a bit broader, because the subject of this question can be found via a search engine:

`--exclude-directories=list` expects *absolute paths* [[1]](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html). This means with `host.org/fu/bar/` you have to write `--exclude-directories=/fu/bar`.

This can be a problem, if you always want to exclude a folder with a specific name, no matter where it is exactly (for example a 'thumbs' folder).

For this we can use `--reject-regex` [[2]](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html) like this: `--reject-regex="/thumbs/"`. Given this is now regex and not a comma-separated string list, we can exclude multiple folders via `regex1|regex2|regex3`: `--reject-regex="/thumbs/|/css/"`. Keep in mind that certain characters like `.` have a special meaning in regex and need to be escaped to be part of a folder name: `"/\.svn/"`.